# Optimize Log Likelihood Model based on Gaussian Process involving Matrix Calculus

Tags: regression, gaussian-process, likelihood, matrix-calculus

Given 
\begin{equation}
\text{temperature(t, y)} = a_0 + a_1t + X(t)
\end{equation}
where temperature(t, year) is the dataset temperature at day $t$ in year $y$. $a_0, a_1 \in \mathbb{R}$, and $X(t)$ is a mean zero, Gaussian process. $T^{(y)}$ is a $122$ dimensional vector collecting the temperatures in year $y$. Let $M$ be a $122 \times 2$ matrix with the first column formed by all $1$'s and the second column formed by the numbers $1$ through $122$.   Letting $a = (a_0, a_1)$, and thinking of $a$ as a column vector. $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix of $X(t)$ for $t=1,2,\dots,122$.
$\Gamma$ is a matrix such that $\Sigma = \sigma^2 \Gamma$ and $\Gamma$ only depends on $\lambda$.
\begin{equation}
L(a_0, a_1, \sigma^2, \lambda) = \prod_{y=2013}^{2016}  \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi \sigma^2)^{122} \text{det} \Gamma}}
\exp[-\frac{(T^{(y)} - Ma)^T \Gamma^{-1} (T^{(y)} - Ma)}{2\sigma^2}],
\end{equation}
Consider $\lambda$ as fixed.  How to take the gradient of $\log L(a_0, a_1, \sigma^2, \lambda)$, with respect to just $a_0, a_1$, and $\sigma^2$ and show that the likelihood is maximized at the following parameter values,
\begin{equation}
a = \frac{1}{4} \sum_{y=2013}^{2016} (M^T \Gamma^{-1} M)^{-1} M^T \Gamma^{-1} T^{(y)}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{4(122)} \sum_{y=2013}^{2016} (T^{(y)} - Ma)^T \Gamma^{-1} (T^{(y)} - Ma)
\end{equation}

Comment: Even if it asks for a gradient calculation, I wonder why a question about Gaussian Process regression is off-topic in this forum. There are plenty of many other questions requiring to calculate gradients in the context of neural-nets, ML etc.